# Primary & Foreign Key Constraints Confusion

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

currently trying to apply foreign keys to my created tables but I'm getting the SQL error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
       gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
       key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
       catalog view
```

I'm at a massive loss on where to go from here, I think everythings in order but I just can't point out what's wrong.

Here are the relavent create and alter scripts i'm using if anybody can point out where i'm going wrong:

Creation of Results & DopingTest:

```
CREATE TABLE Results
(
RaceID NUMBER,
HorseID NUMBER,
JockeyID NUMBER,
Position numeric(2)
);

CREATE TABLE DopingTest
(
RaceID NUMBER,
HorseID NUMBER,
TakenBy varchar2(60)
);
```

And the adding of constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE Results
ADD(
  CONSTRAINT pk_ResultsID
    PRIMARY KEY (RaceID,HorseID));

ALTER TABLE DopingTest
ADD(
  CONSTRAINT pk_DopingTest
    PRIMARY KEY (RaceID, HorseID));

ALTER TABLE Results
ADD(
  CONSTRAINT fk_raceID
    FOREIGN KEY (RaceID)
    REFERENCES Race(RaceID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_horseID
    FOREIGN KEY (HorseID)
    REFERENCES Horse(HorseID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_JockeyID
    FOREIGN KEY (JockeyID)
    REFERENCES Jockey(JockeyID));

ALTER TABLE DopingTest
ADD(
  CONSTRAINT fk_RaceIDDT
    FOREIGN KEY (RaceID)
    REFERENCES Results(RaceID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_HorseIDDT
    FOREIGN KEY (HorseID)
    REFERENCES Results(HorseID));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `results` has a composite primary key, the foreign key would have to reference both components of the key.

```
ALTER TABLE DopingTest
ADD(
  CONSTRAINT fk_RaceIDDT
    FOREIGN KEY (RaceID, HorseID)
    REFERENCES Results(RaceID, HorseID)
);
```

Comment: i was facing a simmilar issues - in my case the column in 2 tables had a small difference , one table had nullable column and other had non nullable - so it is required the columns to be exactly same - data type and nullable property